# T-SQL (Azure Synapse) Dynamic grouping based on unknown number of Primary Keys

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, azure-synapse

I'm tasked with creating a sp that will loop through every table in a supplied schema and find any that do not have unique primary keys (duplicate primary keys). Some tables may have only one column creating the primary key while others may have composite keys with an unknown number of columns.

For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE test
USE TEST
CREATE PROC duplicateCheck @schemaChoice nvarchar(60)= 'test'
CREATE TABLE onePrimary(

      id int,
      orders int,
      orderCustomer varchar(20)
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
CREATE TABLE twoPrimary(
      id int,
      item int,
      color varchar(20),
      size varchar(20),
      PRIMARY KEY(id,item)
    )
INSERT INTO onePrimary
VALUES(1,2,'Brad'),
(2,1,'Lenny'),
(3,1,'Rachel')

INSERT INTO twoPrimary
VALUES(1,1,'yellow','large'),
(2,1,'blue','small')


create table #primaryKey(
       TABLE_NAME varchar(20),
       COLUMN_NAME varchar(20)
    )
SELECT @schemaChoice,
       x.TABLE_NAME,
       x.COLUMN_NAME,
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE x, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS y
    WHERE x.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaChoice
    and y.CONSTRAINT_TYPE like 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

That's where I get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information in Sql Server (and Azure Synapse) using the system views.

The following will list all user tables, the name of the primary key and how many key columns are defined.

```
select Schema_Name(t.schema_id) SchemaName, t.name TableName, i.name PrimaryKey, Count(*) KeyColumnCount
from sys.tables t
join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id and i.is_primary_key = 1
join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = t.object_id and ic.index_id = i.index_id
group by t.name, i.name, Schema_Name(t.schema_id)
order by KeyColumnCount
```

You can add `having count(*)>1` after the `group by` to only list tables with more than 1 key column, and of course any other filtering you need.

Comment: I understand how to reach primary key info, the question is how to find tables in a schema which have duplicate primary keys.

I want to have a stored procedure where I pass the schema name as a parameter and the procedure loops through every table in the schema to find duplicates in each table. Since we don't know the primary key for each table before hand that information has to be added somewhere in the procedure so we know what to group by to find duplicates

Comment: Perhaps I have not fully understood, what do you mean by duplicate primary keys - you can only define one primary key per table. you also mention primary keys defined on 1 column and composite keys and it's the latter I assumed you were referring to, as also indicated by your sample script. The above query finds all the tables that have more than one column in the primary key. You can add a `where Schema_Name(t.schema_id) =@schemaNameParameter` to limit to a specific schema.

Comment: We have a situation in our synapse where we have defined primary keys but tables are still loading with duplicate primary keys. 

Again in a nutshell this is the problem:
We need to find tables that have duplicate primary keys within a given schema dynamically (i.e supply the schema name and the stored procedure spits out tables that have duplicate primary keys.)

The script I gave is essentially the lead-up to what I actually want just so you don't have to re-type.